# How can I return a string literal from a Postgres function?

Tags: postgresql

I got this working to return an integer:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_function() RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
  SELECT 1 AS result;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

But I want it to return a string, so I tweaked it to:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_function() RETURNS TEXT AS $$
  SELECT '1' AS result;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

But this fails with:

```
ERROR:  return type mismatch in function declared to return text
DETAIL:  Actual return type is unknown.
```

What happened?  How can I return the string '1'?

Comment: '1' by default is varchar.   you need to specify explicit typecasting : 

CREATE FUNCTION my_function() RETURNS TEXT AS $$
  SELECT '1'::TEXT AS result;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

Comment: @IlyaDyoshin - Your comment is correct generally, but  '1' by default shows `unknown`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String literals are of type `unknown`. You can explicitly specify the type like this:

```
SELECT TEXT '1' AS result;
```